# ez Publish - cannot add new translation content

Tags: translation, ezpublish

I go to /content/translations on admin panel to add new translation. I choose Translation field then click OK. But the page just remain loading and loading over time. I try to wait an hour but still not add successful. I also try to add other translation. And the result is the same. Can anybody help me?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the function of creating translation is deadlock in database. Need to go through database to stop this deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a normal behavior.

I think that you have a setup issue or something. You should have a look at the logs in the var/logs/*.log files. Also please provide more information like the version of eZ Publish running, PHP version, operating system, etc.

*And, waiting 1 second, maybe 2, is enough, don't waste your time waiting hours, eZ Publish is a fast CMS.*